# Kogito Intermediate catch Event Correlation

Tags: redhat, bpmn, kogito, redhat-bpm, bpmn-engine

I hope someone can help me.
I have two process

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EWD4a.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e8UWv.png)

Log shows me the following message when the first process consumes event throws by the second process.

No matches found for trigger raccolta_dati in process cra_edit. Skipping consumed message CloudEventWrapDataEvent [cloudEvent=CloudEvent{id='c91d80dc-aaa9-43b4-83ae-dc6ce55f5424', source=/process/raccolta_dati, type='raccolta_dati', time=2024-01-30T17:56:57.096033500+01:00, data=JsonCloudEventData{node="string"}, extensions={kogitoproctype=BPMN, kogitoprocinstanceid=d48b1e4e-bc15-4ee7-8456-7b5a3adcc577, kogitoprocist=Active, kogitoprocversion=1.0, kogitoprocid=raccolta_dati}}]

For kafka i would use the same topic for all node events and my configuration is:

mp.messaging.incoming.kogito_incoming_stream.connector=${KOGITO.KAFKA.CONNECTOR}
mp.messaging.incoming.kogito_incoming_stream.topic=${KAFKA.KOGITO.INCOMING-STREAM.TOPIC}
mp.messaging.incoming.kogito_incoming_stream.value.deserializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
mp.messaging.incoming.kogito_incoming_stream.auto.offset.reset=earliest
mp.messaging.incoming.kogito_incoming_stream.group.id=node-events-consumer

mp.messaging.outgoing.kogito_outgoing_stream.connector=${KOGITO.KAFKA.CONNECTOR}
mp.messaging.outgoing.kogito_outgoing_stream.topic=${KAFKA.KOGITO.OUTGOING-STREAM.TOPIC}
mp.messaging.outgoing.kogito_outgoing_stream.value.serializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer

Kogito_incoming_stream and kogito_outgoing_stream have same topic.

Maybe i need to set the correlations but I do not understand where insert this configuration.

Thanks

Comment: Take a look to https://blog.kie.org/2021/09/kogito-process-eventing-add-ons.html. See later comments for intermediate message